# How can I find 3rd object in my array in cypress

Tags: arrays, typescript, csv, sorting, cypress

For my this method

```
static getTemplateItemName() {
  const x = this.templateItem.find('.template-name').contains('Basic elements').scrollIntoView({ensureScrollable: false});
  cy.get('.template-cover').eq(2).within(() =>
    cy.get('.btn-link-primary').contains('Preview').click({force: true});
};
```

I want to remove .eq(2) and give something more soft code, which can use other templeate name also. Can you please suggest how we can do it

Here's my HTML:

```
<div _ngcontent-nbr-c91="" class="template-cover">
  <div _ngcontent-nbr-c91="" class="template-description">
    <div _ngcontent-nbr-c91="" class="template-name">
      <p _ngcontent-nbr-c91="" class="text-xs">Basic elements</p> 
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-nbr-c91="" class="template-actions ng-star-inserted">
      <button _ngcontent-nbr-c91="" class="btn btn-link-primary">Preview</button>
      <button _ngcontent-nbr-c91="" class="btn btn-outline-primary"> Select </button>
    </div>
    <!---->
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the HTML showing the element?

Comment: <div _ngcontent-nbr-c91="" class="template-cover"><div _ngcontent-nbr-c91="" class="template-description"><div _ngcontent-nbr-c91="" class="template-name"><p _ngcontent-nbr-c91="" class="text-xs">Basic elements</p></div><div _ngcontent-nbr-c91="" class="template-actions ng-star-inserted"><button _ngcontent-nbr-c91="" class="btn btn-link-primary">Preview</button><button _ngcontent-nbr-c91="" class="btn btn-outline-primary"> Select </button></div><!----></div></div>

Comment: Is the text `Basic elements` unique in your webpage?

Comment: Yes it name of preview and class for it is text-xs in template-cover

Comment: What I mean is the text `Basic elements` displayed multiple times on your webpage or just once?

Comment: Just once on web page

Answer (score 1):

So instead of `eq(2)` you can use `parent` to reach your template cover element and then using within you can click the Preview button. Something like this:

```js
cy.contains('p', 'Basic elements')
  .parent() //template-name
  .parent() //template-description
  .parent() //template-cover
  .within(() => {
    cy.contains('button', 'Preview').click({force: true})
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you Preview and Select buttons are unique only to the div with `template-cover` you are seeking, then you can easily access.

```js
// make sure we are in correct template
cy.contains('.template-cover', 'Preview')
  .should('be.visible')
  .contains('button', 'Preview')
  .should('be.visible')
  // your element might be covered by another element for you to use force:true
  .click({force:true})
```

If the buttons are not unique to the template then we can go by the template name.

```js
// make sure we are in correct template
cy.contains('.template-cover', 'Basic elements')
  .should('be.visible')
  .contains('button', 'Preview')
  .should('be.visible')
  // your element might be covered by another element for you to use force:true
  .click({force:true})
```